# std::vector::emplace_back error in class with a custom constructor

Tags: c++, stdvector, emplace

My program has a class similar to the following:

```cpp
class IOWorker {
    
    std::thread                                    thread_;
    boost::asio::io_service                        ios_;
    boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work> work_;
    Callback                                       callback_;
    
    static thread_local IOWorker*                  this_thread_worker_;
    
public:
    IOWorker(Callback cb);
    ~IOWorker();
        
    // IO worker threads will call this to fetch their instance
    static IOWorker* getIOWorkerInstance (void) {
        return this_thread_worker_;
    }
};
    
IOWorker::IOWorker (Callback cb) : callback_{std::move(cb)}
{
    work_ = boost::in_place(boost::ref(ios_));
    thread_ = std::thread{[this] () {
        this_thread_worker_ = this;
        ios_.run();
    }};
}
```

Main thread calls the following function to create `IOWorker` instances/threads:

```cpp
std::vector<IOWorker> startIOWorkers(Callback cb)
{
    std::vector<IOWorker> launched_workers;
    launched_workers.reserve(10);
        
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        launched_workers.emplace_back(cb);
    }
    
    return launched_workers;
}
```

But the compilation fails with the following error (pointing to `_Up`):

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'IOWorker'
::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
```

Not sure what changes I need to make in the above class to resolve this error.

I want this class (objects) to be non-copyable, but can be movable.

Comment: The user-declared destructor means that the implicitly-declared [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) will not be created for your class. If all those members are move-constructible, you could write a move constructor by adding `IOWorker(IOWorker&&) = default;` to the class definition.

Comment: It would help you and people on this site if you minimized your example. I am sure you can reproduce the error without thread+network+...

Comment: The other answer is correct, your class is not copyable and`std::vector` doesn't work because in this context because of that. However this doesn't mean that you should make your class copyable at all cost, maybe it simply means that you cannot not store de instances in a vector. Maybe a static array (std::array) or a list (std::list) is good enough for storing many of these instances.